# Minimum value I2C-pull up resistor for arduino

Tags: resistors, i2c, pullup

I'm trying to determine the minimum value of pull resistor for Arduino Uno

The datasheets says; 0,4 Vol for 20 mA Iol. Let's assume VDD = 5V

For formula is:  Rmin=Vcc−0.4V/20mA =  4,6V / 20mA = 230 ohms.

But I saw that people use 0,4V for 3mA. Than the minimal value is 1,6K ohms.

So whats the minimum value of pull-up for arduino?

Comment: Your I2C slave also has to pull down the pins for ack/nack. So you can't use only the Arduino figures to find the minimum value.

Comment: My slaves also have 0,4 Vol for 20 mA

Comment: related: [Is there a correct resistance value for I2C pull-up resistors?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/30792/7036)

Comment: Yea I know, but they use 3mA there. I'm wondering why they use the 3mA. Many devices like arduino can go much higher

Comment: Umm.. where, exactly, are you getting the 0.4V @ 20mA number from? The MCU datasheet says 1.0V max at 20mA, 5V Vdd and max temperature.

Comment: Most I2C slave devices are designed with a 3mA drive capability - eg http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/pcf8574.pdf. You have to select the pull-up for the weakest device on the bus.

Comment: Yea but all of my devices can sink 20mA

Comment: @spehroPefhany Correct; 0,4V is typical value, 1V is max value. But that does not change anything on my question

Comment: @Berkay - I gave you the reason a for why the typical assumption is 3mA drive capability. In addition to being able to provide the current for the pull-up you also need to provide current to discharge the capacitance of the line (the spec says up to 400pF) in a reasonable time. Why do you want to go so low? - it won't improve the performance and will just take more power.

Comment: @KevinWhite I'm driving 800pf of load. So I will use somthing like 900 ohms