How can I connect 8 I2C modules with entirely different addresses on ESP32?
I have to connect 8 different I2C modules to ESP32 without the use of an I2C expander but I couldn't figure how to do it in hardware.
Someone suggested to remove the pullup resistors of each modules. As long as the amount of modules used is below 3 I don't need to remove. But if I had to use 4 or above, I need to remove it. Any suggestions?
I2C Modules:

BMP180 (0x77)
HMC5883l (0x0D)
MPU6050 (0x69)
DS3231 (0x68)
APDS 9960 (0x39)
MAX30102 (0x57)
PCF8574t (0x20)
MAX17048 (0x36)


The suggestion is to do as you are already told. But we don't know anything about your modules, their pull-up resistors being present or absent or their values, or to which voltagr they pull to. So unless you list what modules they are, you need to know if each and all of them work with same 3.3V bus voltage levels as thr ESP.

@Justme so this question was edited, and now you can see the list of the i2c devices im going to use

@candice You said you are using modules but have listed only the chips. The chips are irrelevant. Each module with some chip is unique design, so the question is not if these chips are compatible, but if these modules (that contain some chips) are compatible. We still don't know anything about your modules (except the chips that are on them), so we can't answer how you can use those modules together.

Slave I2C devices should not have any pullups installed. The pullups belong on the ESP32 Master device (where I'm referring to actual resistors, not the MCU's internal GPIO pullups).

For using multiple modules on the same I2C bus, you need to check:

that no module tries to pull the voltage higher than the maximum allowed voltage for any other module (nb: some modules might allow 5V if powered from 5V, but only 3.3V when powered from 3.3V). If you power your ESP and all your modules from the same voltage (3.3V), then you are probably fine. Nb: there could still be modules supplied with 3.3V but using for example 1.8V for the logic part, but as long as you stay with Arduino/Raspberry-Pi/ESP modules, the risk is low. If you go into more "professional" modules, always double check.
that the total of all pull up resistances on a line (SCK or SDA) are in the acceptable range (all the resistors are in parallel). If the total resistance is too low (for example too many modules with integrated pull ups), then you might destroy you modules or prevent them from working (there is too much current when trying to pull down the lines). The lower limit for total resistance is defined by the module with the lowest sink capability. The upper value is harder to define on hobby projects (it depends on the capacitance of the I2C bus (wires + all modules + ESP) and on the speed you want to operate it. For 100kHz I2C, 4.7kΩ or 10kΩ pull up resistors are my default value when I don't want to do full calculations. If your total resistance is <2kΩ, I would recommend to check the sinking capabilities of each device (it might work or not depending on your devices). If <500 ohms, it's very unlikely it will work.
basically, if you can, use a single pull up resistor per line, this way you know where you are.

EDIT: some nice graph of the consequences of too big or too small resistors : https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/473799/301878

Thanks for the answer. So Basically, i need to add 10k resistor pullups (As per the link) to SCL and SDA pins of each modules right?

No, you need to have about 3-10k equivalent resistance for each line (SCK or SDA). Lets take an example for SDA (same applies to SCK) : if module 1 has a 10k pull-up, module 2 has no pull up, module 3 has a 10k pull up. Then the total resistance is 1/(1/10k + 1/10k) = 5k : shoud be fine. Now if module 3 is 4.7k, you have a total resistance of 1/(1/10k+1/4.7k)=3.2k : it will probably still work, but better to check. If you now add modules 4 and 5 with each 3.3k, you now have R_total = 1/(1/10k + 1/4.7k + 1/3.3k +1/3.3k) = 1.09k : you are starting to ask for trouble ...

If your total resistance is too low, yo need to remove some of the pull up resistors. Adding more resistors will only make things worse.
If you don't want to do the math, one solution can be to remove them all, and just add a single 10k resistor for SDA (and another for SCK). Or to remove all restors excepted on a single module.

thanks, now i got it
